# How to create a tile on start screen in Win8 automatically?

Tags: windows, html, windows-8

I am trying to build a win8 application and I want to create a tile on the start screen automatically after user install it.

I did some searching, but all of them were talking about how make tile, but I want it to show on the start screen, not the 'Apps' screen.

Could any one help and tell me how to do that or give me some useful information?

Comment: I think you cannot create a tile before the user has started the app once...

Comment: really? how do you know that? Oh, sorry, I just wanna know why...:-)

Comment: Are you talking about secondary tiles ?

Comment: oh, yeah, I wanna know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 8, all apps will automatically have a tile created for them in the Start Menu during installation; you don't need to take any extra action for this to happen.

In Windows 8.1, this behavior changes and new apps that are installed are NOT automatically added to the user's Start Menu (they will be added to the Apps list).  In Windows 8.1, the user has to explicitly go to the Apps list and add apps to their Start Menu.  I found a quick video of this [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mw5aXmt3c3w).

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to do that ? I mean programly

Comment: Your application's main tile (specified in your app manifest) is added automatically in Windows 8, and there is no way (or need) to do that programmatically. But, if you want to add additional tiles with deep links to certain screens within your app (like in a Weather app, opening straight to the page on New York weather instead of the main Weather screen), you can use secondary tiles. I wrote a blog post on how to do this with code samples at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/19/real-world-secondary-tiles-top-three-tips-for-working-with-secondary-tiles-in-windows-8-apps.aspx.